# How to display line numbers by default in SciTE?

Tags: scite

I am using the lightweight SciTE Text editor and I like it very much.

I would like to configure it in order to see the line numbers displayed when I open it.
I don't want to check the "View\Line Number" menu every time.

I think that I can do it but I don't see the entry in my global options file. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this in *SciTEGlobal.properties*:

```
 # Sizes and visibility in edit pane
line.margin.visible=1
line.margin.width=5
```

Comment: Does not have to be in global. It can even be in user options file. Thank you for the tip. :-)

Comment: This answer would be much better if a link to the documentation that relates `line.margin` and its sub-properties to the display of line numbers.  A search for 'line numbers' at https://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html does the trick.

Answer (score 21):

```
# Sizes and visibility in edit pane
line.margin.visible=1
line.margin.width=2+   # + will expand if needed
```

Comment: There is a typo. I tried to edit it but I can't since there is only 1 char to change. Please change "needet" by "needed"

Comment: I did it for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Having seen the other answers i would say it is more "clean" to save to User options file, because it is a user setting and you might also transfer this setting together with your home directory f.e. when you migrate or copy it for other reason. Also in this cases your scite would still behave like YOU (and possibly other users) expect.

"Go to menu 'Options' and there select 'Open User Options File and
add this line to User options file ".SciTEUser.properties":

```
line.margin.visible=1
line.margin.width=0+   # + will expand if needed
```

additional comment:
for my taste the font of scite in linux is too small and therefore i also added these lines to .SciTEUser.properties:

```
magnification=1
output.magnification=1
```

Comment: Thanks. IMHO, your answer would be perfect if you add this info: "Go to menu 'Options' and there select 'Open User Options File'"

Comment: Thank you very much - i added your hint - sometimes one is blind to see that there is something missing, when explaining to others, because for oneself everything is clear without any further description